# Error al conectar XAMPP en puertos 3306 y 3307

Tags: xampp

Intento abrir XAMPP y activo la opción de **Apache** y **MySQL** dándole en **Start** y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
05:33:50 p.m.  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums
```

Ya intenté cambiar el puerto del `3306` al `3307`, y el servidor está bien escrito que es `127.0.0.1`

También me aparece el siguiente error, del cual se cancela sin yo darle a nada:

```
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  Problem detected!
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\bin\mysqld.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\data\my.ini" "MySQL""!
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
05:47:15 p.m.  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL service...
05:49:21 p.m.  [mysql]  There may be an error, return code: 1223 - El usuario ha cancelado la operación.
```

Comment: Ya hay una instancia corriendo que no se detuvo correctamente y que esta usando el puerto 3306. Revisa en el administrador de tareas y mata el proceso de mariaDB que encuentres.

Comment: @Alfabravo No me aparece ese proceso, aunque finalicé los que decían XAMPP.

Comment: igual yo tengo ese problema, ya intente conectando con XAMPP al puerto 3307 pero luego me quiero conectar con workbench a ese puerto y me dice que no puedo